# web application to be integrated into Microsoft dynamics CRM

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm

I have a web application, which i want to integrate into Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
So, How to test that application in CRM ? 
Do i need to install CRM 2011 ? But I found that it supports Windows Server 2008, not Windows 7.

So, how to go about this as i have no idea of MS CRM ?

Comment: if do you want to access data of CRM in your web application then you can use crm service to fetch data

Answer (score 0):

How you are planning to integrate something into CRM, if you do not have one installed? There is no emulator of CRM around:) If your solution uses only CRM SDK, you can download it easily and compile/test against it. but if you need some more deep integration you will need to have CRM itself. CRM SDK works perfectly on Windows 7.

However I suspect that you will need CRM installed in order to test your app properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up to a 30-day trial at this address:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-free-trial-overview.aspx

to see a CRM environment and test your integration

Comment: I downloaded it, but when i try to install it. It says, that outlook needs to be installed first.
Do i need to install outlook as well, to make it working ?
Also, how is outlook related to CRM, because everywhere on the web i found Microsoft dynamics CRM for outlook and none without outlook ?

Comment: probably you downloaded the outlook client for CRM, that is an optional outlook component for connecting to CRM.
If you go to the site I linked before, you can click on "try it free", complete the registration and you will have a CRM environment for 30 days